# Ember.js pre4 router get other controllers

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing controllers from other controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388249/accessing-controllers-from-other-controllers)

In Ember pre2 and before with the old Router style, you could get other controllers from the router, so if I were in a controller called `PeopleController` I could do something like this

```
App.PeopleController = Ember.Controller.extend({
     some_computed_property: (function() {
          return this.get('target.otherController.property_i_want');
     }).property('target.otherController.property_i_want')
});
```

or from a debug console

```
> App.router.get('otherController.property_i_want')
```

Both of these worked. Pre4 / the new routing style seems to break this. How do I get this functionality with the new router and pre4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `this.controllerFor('other').get('property_i_want')`

See last part of http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/

Comment: Thanks! This works within a controller, but not from the debug console.

Comment: This also doesn't provide a way to handle the `.property('target.otherController.property_i_want')`

Answer (score 3):

I asked a similar question; you can declare dependencies in the current version.

[Accessing controllers from other controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388249/accessing-controllers-from-other-controllers)

Comment: Apparently I didn't do my do diligence, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had a horrible hack:

```
Em.Route.reopen({init:function(){
  window.App.currentRoute = this;
  this._super.apply(this,arguments);
}})
```

Which lets you do things like:

```
App.currentRoute.controllerFor('something');
App.currentRoute.target...
```

EDIT:
Currently, ember supports defining "needs" for controllers, as well as exposes the container for lookups:

```
App.__container__.lookup("controller:application").get("someProperty")

App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
    needs: ["authentication","notifications"],
    init: function(){
       this._super.apply(this,arguments)
       console.log(this.get("controllers.authentication"), this.get("controllers.notifications"))
    }
})
```

Comment: That's clever, I like that :)

Answer (score 2):

To access the controller from the console, set `debugger;` in your code, refresh the browser, that will halt execution where you set the `debugger` statement, then you can access your controller within the scope you're in, using

```
this.controllerFor('abs');
```

This also very useful in debugging template, you can insert `{{debugger;}}` and that gives you access to the whole scope of the template in the console, try for example to find out what your `controller` or your `view` are.