# Ember Navbar needs to show model data upon change

Tags: ember.js

I am working on an application that needs to modify the content of the navbar after login. Here's a basic sketch I put together (with some help from other samples online):
http://jsbin.com/umutag/1/ with this underlying code: http://jsbin.com/umutag/1/edit

How do I get the header view to display model data?

Should I be using a different helper for the template? (e.g. a {{view}}, {{render}}, or {{control}})

BTW, I've scoured this site and others, but most entries are a few months old and I see ember has been changing a lot since then (or I'm missing something obvious). The above example uses Ember 1.0.0 RC6.

Bryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ultimately want to bind the value in the controller (probably `ApplicationController`) that keeps track of whether the user is logged in or not. Since this is pertaining to login, you most likely have something like a SessionController that keeps track of the token. Here's one way to go about it:

```
App.SessionController = Em.Controller.extend({
  token: null,
  username: null,

  isLoggedIn: function() {
    return !!this.get("token");
  }.property("token");

  // ...
});

App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
  needs: "session",
  isLoggedInBinding: "controllers.session.isLoggedIn",
  usernameBinding: "controllers.session.username"

  //...
});
```

And in your navbar in the template:

```
  {{#if isLoggedIn}}
    <li>Logged in as {{username}}</li>
    <li>{{#linkTo "index"}}Home{{/linkTo}}</li>
    <li>{{#linkTo "secret"}}Secret{{/linkTo}}</li>
  {{else}}
    <li>{{#linkTo "login"}}Log in{{/linkTo}}</li>
  {{/if}}
```

Comment: I got it working, but only halfway. I ended up using a {{partial}} template helper so now the header content changes when the 'isAuthenticated' value changes. As here (in coffeescript):
`App.LoginController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
    needs: "session"
    ...
    clickLogin: (e) ->
       ...
       @set("model.IsAuthenticated", true)
       @set("controllers.session.isAuthenticated", true) `

Thanks again for your help.

-Bryan

Comment: One further question, though. Is there a way for the controller to observe a ember-data model object for changes? I tried this, but to no avail:

`App.SessionController = Em.Controller.extend
        username: null
        usernameBinding: 'App.Me.Username'
        isAuthenticated: null
        isAuthenticatedBinding: 'App.Me.IsAuthenticated'
`

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is something like `App.SessionsController` ... `needs: "me"` ... `usernameBinding: "controllers.me.username"`... and so on. You only want `App.MeController` to represent the `Me` model. To "observe" `Me` with `SessionController` that's where the `needs` property came in just like how we used it to observe the transient attributes of `SessionController` in `ApplicationController`.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the tip. I'll give that a try. Is it possible to supply an array for "needs", such as `needs: ["me", "session"]` (e.g. in another controller)

Comment: In short, yes. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14388792/2081133) shows a good example.